# pdftotext returns blank to variable and "Syntax error: Document stream is empty"

Tags: shell, pdftotext

my code is:

`` text=`pdftotext -layout $Input`  ;;  echo "$text" ``

but it returns a empty space string and the Syntax Error: Document Stream is Empty